# HSTS policy not preloaded on non www host

Tags: .htaccess, hsts

i am not very familiar with HSTS , but i try to implement it on my shared webhosting server.

Seems i have gotten it to work on host with www.  but not on apex host.

Hardenize security audit flags it as an issue, audit report: https://www.hardenize.com/report/perroon.eu/1590566369#www_hsts

I do not have access to apache configuration, only .htaccess.

Here is my .htaccess:

```
# Force from HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://$1 [R,L]

# Secure this /secured section
<If "%{HTTPS} == 'on'">
    AuthUserFile "/home/xtreamro/.htpasswds/perroon.eu/passwd"
    AuthName "Restricted Access"
    AuthType Basic
    require valid-user
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
    Header always set X-Frame-Options "deny"
    Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"
    Header always set Content-Security-Policy "img-src *"
    Header always set Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
    Header always set Cache-Control "public"
</If>
```

Extra notes:

- I use IF in .htaccess, to make sure basic auth is done over https.
- My .htaccess is in root directory of my hosting account, not in
  domain folder.

Can someone share some light how should i do this without security audits mentioning it ?

Comment: Your HTTP to HTTPS redirect is entirely invalid?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hardenize report tells you exactly what to do. Submit your website here - https://hstspreload.org/ OR remove preload from your HSTS record.